# How to handle cudaFree on globally instantiated variables

Tags: c++, cuda, global-variables, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a class that I use to instantiate a global variable:

```
class BitUnpackPtrs
{
public:
    ushort* d_dataIn;

    BitUnpackPtrs() : d_dataIn(NULL) {};

    ~BitUnpackPtrs()
    {
        cudaFree(d_dataIn);
    }

    void update(...) { ... }
};
```

The class is instantiated globally as a handle to reduce frequent allocation of cuda memory. However, when my program terminates, cuda-memcheck produces a warning:

> Program hit cudaErrorCudartUnloading (error 29) due to "driver shutting down" on CUDA API call to cudaFree.

What is the proper way to handle this? I could remove the cudaFree, but if this class is used at a non-global level at some later point, that would result in a memory leak. I could use a flag in the constructor to indicate how the memory should be handled.

Alternately, is there a way to detect if the cuda driver is shutting down and not call cudaFree in that instance?

Comment: Don't instantiate global objects of classes that expect to call or must call cuda runtime API functions in the constructor or destructor.   The CUDA runtime initialization/teardown can play havoc on this both at program start up and shut down, depending on exactly what you do in the class constructor and destructor.    There is no way to detect if the cuda driver is shutting down (in a way that will not be flagged in `cuda-memcheck`) and not call `cudaFree` in that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making this object global, instantiate it in your `main()` function (or somewhere that gets called by `main()` and wraps the entire execution of your application). This will ensure your `cudaFree()` call gets called before the CUDA tear-down happens.

Another alternative is to use an `std::shared_ptr` with a [custom deleter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), which calls `cudaFree()`. If you do that, then the `cudaFree()` call will happen after the last "user" destructs its copy of the shared pointer - which is before `main()` is done and before CUDA tear-down.

Comment: I considered using a shared pointer, but the global object is actually part of a library. Ultimately, I think the real solution will require restructuring the code. For the time being, I've added a parameter to the constructor to indicate memory handling of the destructor. I just let the system take care of the cudaFree.

Comment: @AaronS: Fair enough; remember, though, that other users will read this question, and for them the second alternative might still be relevant.